# Select two names from another table by using id from the first table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Lets call them table_a and table_b

table_a

```html
Id      Name
3       John
4       Mary
8       Anna
```

table_b

```html
Id    Name1_Id   Name2_Id  Payment

23       3          8        300
24       4          3        200
25       8          3        300
```

How can i select something like this

**name**(which id equals to Name1_Id) , **name**(which id equals to Name2_Id), **payment**

Sorry for my bad english hope you can understand me.

Answer (score 0):

You need two joins and table aliases:

```
select a1.name, a2.name, b.payment
from table_b as b join
     table_a as a1
     on b.name1_id = a1.id join
     table_a as a2
     on b.name2_id = a2.id
```